# Qt Quick Project with Qt Charts - The program has unexpectedly finished

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtcharts

Problem: The program crashes when I run when the bar chart is included (I build and run from QTCreator).
The bar chart is added inside a rectangle via the Design mode.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Method of Installation: Online Installer

Method of installation of QT Charts: I have it installed both via QT Maintenance Tool and apt.

dash.pro

```
QT += quick charts

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtCharts 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        x: 226
        y: 118
        width: 352
        height: 263
        color: "#5e2a2a"

        ChartView {
            id: bar
            anchors.fill: parent
            BarSeries {
                name: "BarSeries"
                BarSet {
                    values: [2, 2, 3]
                    label: "Set1"
                }

                BarSet {
                    values: [5, 1, 2]
                    label: "Set2"
                }

                BarSet {
                    values: [3, 5, 8]
                    label: "Set3"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: change to `QT += quick charts widgets`, `#include <QApplication>`  and `QApplication app(argc, argv);`

Comment: @eyllanesc Works without adding `widgets` to `QT`. I am not directly using anything listed [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-module.html#details). Why does it work?

Comment: Charts probably already includes widgets: `QT += quick charts`

Comment: @eyllanesc I figured. Then I added the line `QT -= widgets` and it works.

Comment: Then analyze the Makefile, also delete the build folder and recompile. Discovering those mysteries are not my interest, bye.